# Laravel 5.2 Middleware in elfinder

Tags: php, routes, laravel-5, middleware, elfinder

when the middleware is added to the elfinder I confronted with this error, but when I amount equal to the null set thhis problem fixed.

> ```
> 'route' => [
>     'prefix' => 'elfinder',
>     'middleware' => null, //Set to null to disable middleware filter
> ],
> ```

config/elfinder.php:

> ```
> 'route' => [
>     'prefix' => 'elfinder',
>     'middleware' => ['web','auth'], //Set to null to disable middleware filter
> ],
> ```

my problem is:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem solve by under code to `app/Http/Middleware/VerifyCsrfToken.php`

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Middleware;
use Closure;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken as BaseVerifier;

class VerifyCsrfToken extends BaseVerifier
{
/**
 * The URIs that should be excluded from CSRF verification.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $except = [
    'elfinder/ckeditor',
];
public function handle($request, Closure $next)
{
    $regex = '#' . implode('|', $this->except) . '#';

    if ($this->isReading($request) || $this->tokensMatch($request) || preg_match($regex, $request->path()))
    {
        return $this->addCookieToResponse($request, $next($request));
    }

    throw new TokenMismatchException;
}
}
```